# Scaling an array of Images Java

Tags: java, image, scale

I am attempting to rescale an array of images so that they all have the same width and height. I am having trouble returning the array. Any help would be great.

```
  public static Picture[] resize(Picture[] slides, String[] args) {


    int w = 298;
    int h = 298;

    Picture [] source =  new Picture [Integer.parseInt(args[0])];

    for ( int ti = 0; ti < w; ti++){
        for (int tj = 0; tj < h; tj++){
            Picture [] target = new Picture[ti+1];
            int si = tj * source[ti].width()/w;
            int sj = tj * source[tj].height()/h;
            target[ti].set(ti, tj, source[0].get(si, sj));
        }
    }
    return target;   
}
```

Comment: I have no idea how this code is supposed to work. Why are you creating  an array of pictures with as many elements as how many pixels you went over in a source picture horizontally? Why are you never creating the target `Picture` objects, and setting pixels of an `target[ti]` that will obviously be `null`? Why are you only ever accessing the `0`th element of `source`? I think you need to go back to basics of how to use arrays in the first place: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: (Anyway, voting to close because the code sample above is pretty much beyond fixing, and there's a major XY problem present in the question.)

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a bit unclear, and your source code is confusing. It seems you just need to edit the array that is passed in. You could modify this so that it copies the input array and creates a new array, `System.arraycopy()` would accomplish this.

I have attempted to answer what I believe you needed, however I do not know you API for your Picture class. You could use `set(...)` like you have in your example instead of the API calls I have used.

```
public static Picture[] resize(Picture[] slides, String[] args) {
    int w = 298;
    int h = 298;

    for(Picture i : slides) {
        i.setHeight(h);
        i.setWidth(w);
    }
    return slides;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The array of `Pictures` called `target`, will only exist within the scope of the block in which it was declared. The scope in which the `target` array can be referenced is marked by the opening and closing brackets of the innermost for loop.

In order to be able to refer to `target` at the line where you have the return statement you will need declare it outside both for loops.

As to the rest of the code, as others have noted, it is not clear what is going on.

The `slides` parameter is unused : if you are not using it remove it.

The `args` parameter is poorly named: rename it to indicate its contents.

Carrying out these steps will make it easier for us to help you further.